# Parsing a list of lists from Python to js

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a list into js.

I have tried a few workarounds but I can't seem to access the array to begin looping through.

```py
def parse_list(request):

    first_list = [
        ['Harlem Babies Limited', 'Harlem Babies Limited', 52.0561, 1.154311],
        ['Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd',  'Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd',  51.8866354323239,  0.185223639282133],
        ['Marvel Limited', 'Marvel Limited',52.5653341835845, -0.242548375987545],
        ['Mantaray Marketing Limited',  'Mantaray Marketing Limited',  52.331251,  0.332465]
        ]

    second_list = json.dumps(first_list)

    return render(request,'temp.html', 'second_list':second_list)
```

```html
Template
<html>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var second_list = '{{second_list}}';
</script>
</html>
```

I expected the outcome to be...

```js
second_list = [
    ['Harlem Babies Limited', 'Harlem Babies Limited', 52.0561, 1.154311],
    ['Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd',
  'Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd',
  51.8866354323239,
  0.185223639282133],
    ['Marvel Limited', 'Marvel Limited', 52.5653341835845, -0.242548375987545],
    ['Mantaray Marketing Limited',
  'Mantaray Marketing Limited',
  52.331251,
  0.332465]
]
```

But the actual output is...

```py
second_list = "[[&quot;Harlem Babies Limited&quot;, &quot;Harlem Babies Limited&quot;, 52.0561, 1.154311], [&quot;Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd&quot;, &quot;Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd&quot;, 51.8866354323239, 0.185223639282133], [&quot;Marvel Limited&quot;, &quot;Marvel Limited&quot;, 52.5653341835845, -0.242548375987545], [&quot;Mantaray Marketing Limited&quot;, &quot;Mantaray Marketing Limited&quot;, 52.331251, 0.332465]]"
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `'` from the javascript wrapping the mustache braces?

Comment: Have you tried {{second_list | safe}}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using django.

You need to pass the json through as is without html escaping.
You can do this by using the [safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var second_list = {{second_list|safe}};
</script>
```

Comment: This does change the parsed list into something that resembles an array but it's still a block of text. ```"[["Harlem Babies Limited", "Harlem Babies Limited", 52.0561, 1.154311], ["Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd", "Guardians of the Galaxy Ltd", 51.8866354323239, 0.185223639282133], ["Marvel Limited", "Marvel Limited", 52.5653341835845, -0.242548375987545], ["Mantaray Marketing Limited", "Mantaray Marketing Limited", 52.331251, 0.332465]]"
```

Comment: Do want to get an array in your javascript file?

Comment: @BobbyStearman did you remove the single quotes like in my example? If you remove them it should be an object as expected. :)

Comment: @Turtlefight Thanks, No I didn't initially as it Sublime highlights it as a syntax error i.e. the last curly bracket is highlighted red. Everything seems to work now!